# Get data from specific time period

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datetime

I have an aspx document that returns a list of incoming flights from a database in the form of an HTML table. It displays all flights from the current day. The part that generates the rows is:

```
    string fechha = dias + "/" + mess + "/" + años;
    string fecVuel = fechha;

    for (int i = 0; i <= num - 1; i++)
    {
        string hora = xl.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[5].InnerText;
        fecVuel = xl.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
        if (fecVuel == fechha)
        {
            fila = new TableRow();
```

What I would like is to have it only get flights that match an *specific time period*, like 2 hours before and after the current time. In the code, the value of `string hora` is the time of flight retrieved from the db.

I tried adding a current time variable with `rightnow = DateTime.Now.Hour;` and adding a conditional, like this:

```
if (fecVuel == fecha && ((hora >= rightnow - 2) || (hora <= rightnow + 2))) {...
```

But it's still generating the entire table. I even tried changing it to `fecVuel != fecha` but it changes nothing :S I'm not too good with asp, and I'm using Notepad++ for edits. Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you, I keep forgetting they're not the same. This is a new language for me.

Comment: Also, don't do `i <= num - 1` in your for loop. It's an unnecessary operation, just do `i < num`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say right now, it's 14:00

Two hours ago it was 12:00.  In two hours it will be 16:00.

Right now (14:00) will always satisfy one of the two conditions:

Greater than 12:00 OR less than 16:00.

If you change the OR to AND, both conditions must be satisfied.

```
if (fecVuel == fecha && ((hora >= rightnow - 2) && (hora <= rightnow + 2)))
```

Only times between 14:00 and 16:00 (not inclusive those times) are selected if you use AND.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll code right away (I knew it had to be something ridiculously simple!)

Comment: Yes, but i can't seem to upvote yet. I'm a noob at stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the table is going to match your statement, because what this says:
`if (fecVuel == fecha && (( rightnow - 2 <= hora ) || (hora <= rightnow + 2))) {...`

it says that anything `(rightnow - 2 <= hora) OR (hora <= rightnow + 2)` --- and everything is going to equal one or the other of the terms, whether it's 18 hours before your target time or 99 hours past your target time.

What you need is: `((rightnow - 2) <= hora) && (hora <= (rightnow + 2))`

so, change your `||` to an `&&`, and you should get the results you are after.